# Need to format a specific range out of an array based on the name of a cell. VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

So, we have a cell in A6 with the name of a company,

throughout the page we have that same name with some data in the columns next to it (A:D) within (It is consistently four columns.)

I need to find the rows that have the same name as A6 and apply a thick border, italics, and bold around that selection.

I first started off by using conditional formatting, but I don't believe we can apply a thick outside border to those selections. Which is a problem in and of itself, but I also would prefer not to have to include data outside of the given excel.

Trying to match up Test seen in top left and match it with whats found in C21:
[image]

However, this value will move around so I cant just hard code it to format a specific section.

Comment: Sounds like you need to search a range of cells for a value, then format that cell once found.  What code have you tried so far?

Comment: CF doesn't allow for thick borders, not does it seem to allow for "outside" border, since it's evaluated cell-by-cell.  If you can live with thin borders you could do it with 3 CF rules: one for each end and one for the middle cells.  Or just drop the end borders.

Comment: @TimWilliams - have a solution that way, just a little messy, just wanted to see if there was a way to code it instead. Thank you!

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor So, I have to see if I can find it, however, I was thinking of a for loop that would go through and check each cell to see if it matched with the cell found in A6, then could grab the three cells next to it in a range and put a border on them all while also putting them in italics and bold. I'll let you know what I try when I give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Cell Formatting (Thick Borders)

[image]

**Sheet Module, e.g. `Sheet1(Sheet1)`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TARGET_CELL As String = "A6"
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As String = "C13:F13"
    Const DST_CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 1
 
    Dim tCell As Range: Set tCell = Me.Range(TARGET_CELL)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With Me.Range(DST_FIRST_ROW)
        Set drg = .Worksheet.Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown))
    End With
    
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = drg.Columns(DST_CRITERIA_COLUMN)
    
    If Intersect(Union(tCell, dcrg), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drIndices(): drIndices = Application.Match(dcrg, Array(tCell.Value), 0)
    
    Dim durg As Range, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(drIndices, 1)
        If IsNumeric(drIndices(r, 1)) Then
            If durg Is Nothing Then
                Set durg = drg.Rows(r)
            Else
                Set durg = Union(durg, drg.Rows(r))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Reset formatting.
    With drg
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.Italic = False
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        .BorderAround , xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
    End With
    
    If durg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Apply new formatting.
    With durg
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Italic = True
        Dim rrg As Range
        For Each rrg In durg.Rows
            rrg.BorderAround , xlThick
        Next rrg
    End With
    
End Sub
```